How to Handling Many Components with Individual Requests in App Router
I'm currently working on a project where my pages are composed of many components, each with its own API request. I'm using the app router and have fully implemented streaming and for rendering.
While this approach works, I'm concerned about potential issues that might arise when the number of components increases significantly
I'd love to hear your thoughts, experiences, and any best practices you can share for managing many components with individual requests in an app router setup. Any advice or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated!
Here's a simplified version of my current code:
code image here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
